# CreateJS - Measuring FPS in RAF (requestAnimationFrame) mode

Tags: easeljs, createjs

I am using CreateJS in the RAF mode

```
createjs.Ticker.timingMode = createjs.Ticker.RAF;
```

How do I integrate with for instance [stats.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js) measure the browser's FPS?

Or is there any different, recommended way to measure the FPS with CreateJS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to integrate using the instructions on the [stats.js GitHub page](https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js/)

Essentially:

```
c.Ticker.on("tick", tick, this);
function tick(evt) {
   stats.begin();
   // do stuff, like stage.update();
   stats.end();
}
```

Alternatively, you could look at `Ticker.getMeasuredFPS` and `Ticker.getMeasuredTickTime`.